# How to pass and parse a list of strings from command line with argparse.ArgumentParser in Python?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to pass a list of names into my program written in Python from console. For instance, I would like to use a way similar to this (I know it shouldn't work because of `bash`):

```
$ python myprog.py -n name1 name2
```

So, I tried this code:

```
# myprog.py

from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-n', '--names-list', default=[])
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.names_list) # I need ['name1', 'name2'] here
```

That led to the error:

```
usage: myprog.py [-h] [-n NAMES_LIST]
myprog.py: error: unrecognized arguments: name2
```

I know I could pass the names with quotes `"name1 name2"` and split it in my code `args.names_list.split()`. But I'm curious, is there a better way to pass the list of strings via `argparse` module.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You need to define `--names-list` to take an arbitrary number of arguments.

```
parser.add_argument('-n', '--names-list', nargs='+', default=[])
```

Note that options with arbitrary number of arguments don't typically play well with positional arguments, though:

```
# Is this 4 arguments to -n, or
# 3 arguments and a single positional argument, or ...
myprog.py -n a b c d
```

Comment: not possible with the `--arg=value` syntax? like `--arg="one, two, three"` or similar without splitting?

Comment: The OP already acknowledged that the string could be split after `parse_args` is called.

Answer (score 17):

You need to use `nargs`:

```
parser.add_argument('-n', '--names-list', nargs="*")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

Answer (score 4):

```
parser.add_argument('-n', '--names-list', default=[], nargs='+')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to repeat the argument on the command line.

To do this, change the action to append.

```
parser.add_argument('-n', '--names-list', action="append")
```

From the terminal you can call:

```
python myprog.py -n name1 -n name2 -n name3
```

And the result will be:

```
Namespace(n=['name1', 'name2', 'name3'])
```