# How to parse multiple function name to python command line arguments?

Tags: python

I have few methods in a class, and I want to allow the user to run their desired methods only by parsing the method name, but I'm stuck at the argparser code, would like to ask for advices here

Basically I want to accomplish something like below

`python3 test.py -ip 10.10.10.100 -op method1 method2 method3 ...`

in my code

```
class myClass(parentClass):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """
        Setup target system
        """
        try:
            super().__init__()

            self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
            self.parser.add_argument('-ip', help='IP address of target system')
            self.parser.add_argument('-op', help='User desired options')
            self.args, unknown = self.parser.parse_known_args()
        except Exception as exp:
            print(f'Error: {exp}')
    
    def method1(self):
        pass

    def method2(self):
        pass

    def run_prog(self):
        # append user desired method into a list?
        # loop through the list and execute each method
        for i in the_list:
            fn = getattr(self, i)
            fn()
```

*I have to put argparse in `__init__` to follow my org standardization

Comment: I was about to suggest sys.argv, but I suppose your organization  prefers to use argparser

Comment: @JonathanTaylor I was trying sys.argv, per my understanding, it depends on the position such as `sys.argv[3:]`, but there could be other flag in front the `-op` flag and make the position (index) changed, perhaps you could suggest another way round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding the [nargs='+'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786174/how-to-pass-and-parse-a-list-of-strings-from-command-line-with-argparse-argument) option when declaring the `-op` argument parser?

`self.parser.add_argument('-op', help='User desired options', nargs='+')`

Comment: Cool! Learned something new!